# How to set sleep time in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to add 2 sec sleep before `window.location.href` runs.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"price",
    method:"POST",
    }).done(function (data) {
        var origin = window.location.origin;
        // I need add 2 sec sleep
        window.location.href = origin + "/flight/ticket/" + data;
    }).error(function (xhr, opt, error) {
        $('#trustCaptcha').show();
        $('#getTicket').hide();
    }
);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()` method.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "price",
  method: "POST",
}).done(function(data) {
  var origin = window.location.origin;
  // I need add 2 sec sleep
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = origin + "/flight/ticket/" + data;
  }, 2000);
}).error(function(xhr, opt, error) {
  $('#trustCaptcha').show();
  $('#getTicket').hide();
});
```

You can read more about this method **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)**.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout()` to delay logic execution. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"price",
  method:"POST",
}).done(function (data) {
  var origin = window.location.origin;
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = origin + "/flight/ticket/" + data;
  }, 2000); // 2000ms = 2 seconds
}).error(function (xhr, opt, error) {
  $('#trustCaptcha').show();
  $('#getTicket').hide();
});
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer that helped